# Take input values and add to another

Tags: javascript, html

I have several inputs with values and I intend to put the value in each one adding to the total value and at the end when the user puts some value in "received value" he subtracts and inserts a value in the change input.

```js
    <script>
    $('money1').keyup(function(){
    $('#totalmoney').val($(this).val());
});
    $('#totalreceived').keyup(function () {
    var received = $('#totalreceived').value;
    var money = $('#totalmoney').value;
    var back = received - money;
    $('#back').val(back);
});
    </script>
```

```html
  <div class="col-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Money 1" name="money1" id="money1" required>
  </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Money 2" name="money2" id="money2">
  </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Money 3" name="money3" id="money3">
  </div>

<label for="example-email-input"  class="col-2 col-form-label">Total Money</label><input class="col-form-label" id="totalmoney" type="text" disabled></input>
<label for="example-email-input"  class="col-2 col-form-label">Total Received</label><input class="col-form-label" id="totalreceived" type="text"></input>
<label for="example-email-input"  class="col-2 col-form-label">Back</label><input class="col-form-label" id="back" type="text" disabled></input></center>
```

This value is not adding up.

Comment: can you explain more clearly what you are  trying to do?

Comment: `$('money1').keyup(function(){ ` needs to be `    $('#money1').keyup(function(){` . same for totalreceived -> #totalreceived,totalmoney -> #totalmoney I bet this is not the WHOLE code.. as parts are missing..

Comment: The value of the inputs "money1 and money2 and money3" is added up and displayed in the Total Money input. Input "Back" is the subtraction of input "total money and input "money received"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sum =0;
    $('.form-control').keyup(function(){
    
    
    sum =  sum +  parseFloat($(this).val()); 
    
    $('#totalreceived').val((sum)) 
    
    

});
   
     $('#totalmoney').keyup(function(){
     
    
    var back = $('#totalreceived').val() -  $('#totalmoney').val();
    $('#back').val(back);
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Money 1" name="money1" id="money1" required>
  </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Money 2" name="money2" id="money2">
  </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Money 3" name="money3" id="money3">
  </div>
  

<label for="example-email-input"  class="col-2 col-form-label">Total Money</label>

<input class="col-form-label " id="totalmoney" type="text" > 
<label for="example-email-input"  class="col-2 col-form-label">Total Received</label>
<input class="col-form-label" id="totalreceived" type="text">
<label for="example-email-input"  class="col-2 col-form-label">Back</label>
<input class="col-form-label" id="back" type="text" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just misplaces a few parentheses and forgot some `#` to clarify to target an `id`:

```
$('#money1').keyup(function () {
    $('#totalreceived').val($(this).val());
    var back = $('#totalreceived').value - $('#totalmoney').value;
    $('#back').val(back);
});
```

Comment: This code does not inform the value of the input back.

The Input Back will be the subtraction of the total money and total received

Comment: Something like that:                                                       
$('#totalreceived').keyup(function () {
  $('#back').val($('#totalreceived').value - $('#totalmoney').value);
});